# DLQ, until-successful and exceptions

Tags: mule

I am using until-successful in order to retry a connection several times,  in the case of me the retry policy being exhausted, i would like to log the error gracefully (without raising an exception).
I've tried using a default-exception-strategy, like so:

```
<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore"
        deadLetterQueue-ref="ErrorHandler" maxRetries="${TMSService.numOfRetries}"
        secondsBetweenRetries="${TMSService.retrySecInterval}">
        <outbound-endpoint address="${TMSService.host}" />
    </until-successful>
    <default-exception-strategy>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="ErrorMsgs" />
    </default-exception-strategy>
```

But that still wont catch that exception, what would be the correct way to handle this?

Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The until-successful message processor doesn't throw exceptions (unless a technical issue, maybe with its object store), prevents it to enqueue the message for delivery.

If you want to find out the exception that caused the last delivery error, you should find at in the exception payload of the MuleMessage that gets dispatched to your DLQ endpoint.

Comment: Hmm... thanks (yet again) for your response. But even if i do manage to log the exception that is inside the mulemessage. there is still an exception being thrown (and not caught) - I mean, if i look in eclipse there is still an exception shown (and not caught properly).

Comment: That shouldn't be the case: please file a JIRA at MuleSoft, complete with the full stacktrace that is not handled properly when the policy is exhausted. Please indicate the JIRA number here.